# is RabbitMQ queueing system unnecessary in a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I have just been certified CKAD (Kubernetes Application Developer) by The Linux Foundation.

And from now on I am wondering : is RabbitMQ queueing system unnecessary in a Kubernetes cluster ?

We use workers with queueing system in order to avoid http 30 seconds timeout : let's say for example we have a microservice which generates big pdf documents in average of 50 seconds each and you have 20 documents to generate right now, the classical schema would be to make a worker which will queue each documents one by one (this is the case for the company I have been working for lately)

But in a Kubernetes cluster by default there is no timeout for http request going inside the cluster. You can wait 1000 seconds without any issue (20 documents * 50 seconds = 1000 seconds)

With this last point, is it enought to say that RabbitMQ queueing system (via the amqplib module) is unuseful in a Kubernetes cluster ? moreover Kubernetes manages so well load balancing on each of your microservice replicas...

Answer (score 3):

> But in a Kubernetes cluster by default there is no timeout for http request going inside the cluster.

Not sure where you got that idea. Depending on your config there might be no timeouts at the proxy level but there's still client and server timeouts to consider. Kubernetes doesn't change what you deploy, just how you deploy it. There's certainly other options than RabbitMQ specifically, and other system architectures you could consider, but "queue workers" is still a very common pattern and likely will be forever even as the tech around it changes.

Comment: Right here my friend https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/ check this --request-timeout string     Default: "0"

Comment: Then a request coming from the cluster and staying in the cluster won't ever encounter timeout isn't right ?

Comment: That's specifically in reference to the client-side timeout for kubectl making requests to kube-apiserver. It has nothing to do with your own applications and traffic.

Comment: then what about https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/ here --runtime-request-timeout duration     Default: 2m0s

Comment: That's the server timeout for some kubelet-hosted APIs. Again, this has nothing to do with your applications. You can configure any server timeouts in your web servers you want but you generally can't control the client timeout in the users' browsers. Kubernetes is not magic, it doesn't change how webapps work.

Comment: In the environment I work in, there are a couple of layers (proxies, service meshes, client wrappers) that typically impose a 60-second HTTP timeout, even though everything is running in Kubernetes.  I tend to encourage developers to aim for < 1 s latency for synchronous calls, or else move things to a queue.

Comment: @coderanger you are a little wrong this is in the CKAD learning "Developers new to Kubernetes sometimes assume it is another virtual-machine manager, similar to what they have been using for decades, and continue to develop applications in the same way as prior to using Kubernetes. This is a mistake. The decoupled, transient, microservice architecture is not the same. Most legacy applications will need to be rewritten to optimally run in a cloud."

Comment: @coderanger you are right, the users' browsers https request will always be 30 seconds timeout. But once you get that https request that demands the famous 20 pdf documents, you trigger 20 new http request from within the cluster. Then you inform the users' browser when the operation is ended via websocket (with a loader in percentage)

Comment: @ThomasAumaitre I assure you I know how to use Kubernetes (feel free to look me up), the CNCF can say whatever they want and they are not the final arbiters of anything. Some architectures are harder to translate into a Kubernetes environment and some are easier, but none are impossible and "queue workers" is too generic of a pattern to say one way or the other on that. RabbitMQ itself is a bit annoying to run in K8s because mnesia cares a lot about hostnames but fortunately StatefulSets solve that problem.

Comment: impressed, I saw your github profile you look overwhelmed, @DavidMaze just said he has a 60-sec http timeout in its Kubernetes cluster, it's quite enought to do whatever you want. Moreover 50 sec to generate a pdf document means my last company's code was really shitty, should be 25 sec. You combine this with a good service mesh like Linkerd in order to spot easily potential http timeouts with their payload for retry, if there are some. Then you remove RabbitMQ that cost a fortune to the company in consulting and maintenance. You can also increase replicas number in auto scale mode.

Comment: Let's say you never reach a threshold of more than 200 documents to generate at the same time. You just open 200 replicas of your microservice and you are good to go, RabbitMQ is useless in this case. Do you think the replicas autoscale mode respond fast enought to open 200 container in a clap of fingers ? my last question...